# Compile Android with JDK 1.7 - Android Development Tool

Tags: java, android, compiler-construction

I have a source code which currently I use Java Compiler 1.6 to compile it, I want to use 1.7 version instead, I go to project properties and in Java Compiler section I change "Compiler Compliance" to 1.7, but when I build the project I get an error:

> Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use >Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

When I do its recommendation, It change the compiler to 1.6 again. I'm using Android Development Tool.

Thx

Answer (score 8):

Android SDK does not support JDK 1.7 and thats the reason you are not allowed to use it for Compiler compliance. You need to use JDK 1.6 as mentioned under the `System requirements` here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

**UPDATE**
From Android Studio 0.3.2 onwards, there seems to be a support for Java 7 features: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio032released

Comment: Yes I saw that, but in some groups and forums I read that some people use it, Do you have any idea how?!

Comment: @user445891 Even if you compile your code successfully using JDK 1.7 somehow then whey you try to deploy it on the device it will fail to load JRE1.7. You will lead no where.

Comment: In switch-case that key is string, Eclipse IDE says "Cannot switch on a value of type String dor source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum constants are premitted. Change project compliance and JRE to 1.7". What ca i do now?

Comment: This is no longer true.  v23 of the tools supports Java 7 / JDK 1.7.